# Ошибка в void DestroyBodies(vector & bodies)

Tags: c++

```
void DestroyBodies(vector<CBody*> & bodies)
{

    for (vector<CBody>::iterator it = bodies.begin(); it != bodies.end(); ++it)
    {
        delete *it;
        *it = NULL;
    }
}
```

Что мне делать? Выводит ошибки

- error C2259: 'CBody' : cannot
     instantiate abstract class (похоже в
     этом вся проблема)

и соответственно:

- error C2440: 'initializing' :  cannot
     convert from
     'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
     to
     'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
- error C2679: binary '!=' : no
     operator found which takes a
     right-hand operand of type
     'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
     (or there is no acceptable
     conversion)
- error C2440: 'delete' : cannot
     convert from 'CBody' to 'void *'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле for пропущен * в `vector<CBody>::iterator`. Но, предполагаю, проблема не в этом. Выложите код класса CBody.

Comment: Да нет, оказалось только в этом) Спасибо большое)